# Retrieve Provider list with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, provider, riverpod

Is it possible to retrieve all (active) Provider list with Riverpod?

This will help to analyze various thing if we use a lot of Provider, like when we forgot to add `autoDispose` on Provider that is not listened anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Riverpod has a special class [ProviderObserver](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/provider_observer/) for analyzing all providers.